# App installation(?) being blocked on user's Win10 machine, Get-WmiObject

Tags: powershell, windows-10

We have a small custom data-conversion application developed in .Net+WinForms. We distribute it as a ZIPped .exe, no installer or anything. One of our customers is having the installation blocked. None of the other users at the same company are having any problems.

The error is a screen snap from an unidentified app and I'm typing this in, forgive any fat-fingers. It says the category is "script", and the details are:

```
Script Command: if (Get-WmiObject Win32_USBControlerDevice...
```

Googling that, it seems this is part of a PowerShell script? Can anyone offer a reason this might be happening? Perhaps part of unzipping or some other process? Does Window's own security check run scripts perhaps?

Comment: If you have the screen snap, why is the app 'unidentified'?  Why don't you just have your customer tell you what app is producing the event/log?  If you're saying that PowerShell is the thing blocking you, then given the very small snip you've provided, it appears the person loading your self-executing ZIP is trying to launch it from a USB device and there is software on that machine or is applicable to his context (admin or non-admin), that is preventing it.

Comment: The appears to be "Cylance", which I had never heard of. The app is in his download folder, not a USB drive or anything similar.

Comment: 'Cylance' is a cyber defense tool -- Host Intrusion Prevention/Detection tool.  It appears this user or this machine has a policy in their security posture that's blocking the installation of your software.  You should push back and tell them to talk to their security engineers.